# Line-notify why 'Invalid stickerPackageId' even i entered the correct ID number

Tags: python, line

I don't understand why 'Invalid stickerPackageId' even i entered the correct ID number

https://developers.line.biz/media/messaging-api/sticker_list.pdf

I used the first sticker.

```
import requests

def Sticker(stickerPackageID,stickerID):
    url = 'https://notify-api.line.me/api/notify'
    token = '1Nnlpa5Ydf0oAYZ07E4thR9AY3KNABNhisIpd9shfbD'
    headers = {'content-type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded','Authorization':'Bearer '+token}  
    sticker = {'message':" ",'stickerPackageId':stickerPackageID,'stickerId':stickerID}
    r = requests.post(url, headers=headers , data = sticker)
    print (r.text)

Sticker(11537,52002734)
```

result

```
{"status":400,"message":"Invalid stickerPackageId."}
```